# Static Analyzer - Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, static-analysis

In Xcode while releasing the object in dealloc method by like [self.object release] this line is shown as memory leak using static code analyzer but it not showing as leak while running instruments.

Here my question is what is the different BWN `[self.object release]` and just `[object release]`

Please clarify this,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.object` actually calls the getter method (`[self object]`), which returns the instance variable `object` (or depending how is synthesized), but the instance variable actually holds the retained object, so you must do `[object release]`. It's good practice to synthesize your properties with: `@synthesize object = _object` so you don't get confused of the property and the instance variable - your property will be `self.object`, but the instance variable will be `_object` and you will call `[_object release];`

Answer (score 3):

instead of doing -

```
[self.object release]
```

you need to do -

```
self.object = nil; or [object release];
```

[self.object release] will send the release call to the object returned by getter of property. And result will depend whether the property is defined as assign / copy / retain.